# How do you change an objects transparency when it is moved in corona sdk?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am trying to create a drag-able square, which changes its transparency the closer it goes to the center of the screen (from being invisible in the sides to being completely visible in the center, like in the pictures below)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What do you do so far? For opacity use [`alpha`](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/DisplayObject/alpha.html) property of display object.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `alpha` and `transition` to achieve that try below code , It should work .. below code changes square opacity from **0 to 100%** over a time period of **1.5** seconds while moving

```
display.setDefault( "background", 80/255 )
local square = display.newRect(  0, display.contentHeight/2, 100, 100 )
square.anchorChildren = true
square:setFillColor( 255,255,0 )
square.alpha = 0

local w,h = display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight


transition.moveTo( square, { x = w/2, y = h/2, time=1500 , alpha = 1.0} )
```